# Fill drill holes in 3/16" steel plate — without welder

Tags: steel, hole

I have two 1/4" holes in a 3/16" thick steel plate (part of a truck rack). I want to fill the holes with steel, but I don't have a welder.

How can I fill in the holes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can fill the holes with a large sheet metal screw. And grind down both ends of the screw to make it flush with the plate.

---

The side with the pointy ends of the screws:

[image]

The side with the heads of the screws:

[image]

The screws were oversized for the hole. It took a lot of force to get the screws into the holes.

I tried using a [cordless impact driver](https://www.amazon.ca/Milwaukee-2656-20-Lithium-Impact-Lighting/dp/B00I3POGXQ/ref=asc_df_B00I3POGXQ/?tag=googleshopc0c-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=292954213126&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14781243909448870025&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=2124&hvtargid=pla-556447172351&th=1) to insert the screws, but it wasn't powerful enough. So I used a screw bit with a ratchet instead. That worked well for the first screw. But with the second screw, the head of the screw broke off before the screw was fully inserted into the hole.

[image]

Note: I would suggest using a socket-to-screw-bit adapter that is ***magnetic*** or ***snaps into place***, instead of a regular 1/4" socket that only loosely slides onto the bit. A proper adapter would have prevented the screw bit from falling out of the adapter, which was a nuisance.

Comment: This seems like a good short term solution, but I bet overtime they will loosen and fall out. That would be due to both vibration as well as corrosion. A spot of paint might help both conditions.